# AttributeError of hmmlearn from python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to solve this problem.

**Error code**

```py
from hmmlearn import hmm
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=5, n_iter=100)
model.covars_
```

**Error sentence**

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-8ccf3a3ae39c> in <module>
----> 1 model.covars_

/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hmmlearn/hmm.py in covars_(self)
    161     def covars_(self):
    162         """Return covars as a full matrix."""
--> 163         return fill_covars(self._covars_, self.covariance_type,
    164                            self.n_components, self.n_features)
    165 

AttributeError: 'GaussianHMM' object has no attribute '_covars_'
```

**My trying**

substitute correct shape of matrix for *model.covars_*.

other variable (ex. *model.startprob_,model.transmat_,model.means_*) of error has solved this way.

but *model.covars_* has not solved.

Comment: Did you try updating the hmmlearn library?

Comment: Yes, it`s up to date.